# Erro ao rodar projeto react native "A problem occurred configuring project ':app'" no Linux manjaro

Tags: android, android-studio, linux, react-native

eu estava instalando o react native seguindo os passos do facebook, e aí quando fui testar com o comando react-native run-android aconteceu esse erro.
já configurei o android SDK no android studio, mas pelo jeito não funcionou, não sei oque aconteceu, qualquer ajuda eu agradeço.
meu SO é o linux manjaro, sou iniciante qualquer erro me perdoem.

```
[bruno@bruno-pc AwesomeProject]$ sudo react-native run-android
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/home/bruno/AwesomeProject/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/home/bruno/AwesomeProject/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:639:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:657:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (/home/bruno/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:75:39)
    at buildAndRun (/home/bruno/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:137:41)
    at then.result (/home/bruno/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:103:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver este problema de "SDK location not found" existe duas opções. Uma delas seria criar um arquivo local.properties dentro da pasta "Android" que está na raiz do seu projeto, e inserir o caminho para o SDK. Exemplo:

```
sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk
```

Porem, a forma recomendada é editar o arquivo .bash_profile. Exemplo:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Para instalar, dê uma olhada neste tutorial em português:

https://docs.rocketseat.dev/ambiente-react-native/android/linux

Comment: é realmente eu não tinha feito isso ainda, mas ainda não funcionou :/

Answer (score 0):

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5Otz.png)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]